# How to keep session parameters upon switching to another RAC node?

Tags: oracle

I have Oracle RAC 10g environment with two nodes.
On connection we set the session TIME_ZONE  using ALTER SESSION. 
But, on switching the session to another node , RAC lost TIME_SONE settings.

*How to keep session parameters upon switching to another RAC node?*
Tx

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [Transparent Application Failover](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/rac.112/e16795/hafeats.htm#BABDCBHH) there is probably no easy way to do this:

> You must also reexecute any session customizations, in other words,
>   ALTER SESSION statements, after failover has occurred.

There may be workarounds, depending on how you set the session settings.  For example, if all the relevant sessions come from the same application, computer, etc., you can use a logon trigger that sets the same settings.  You can find the relevent session using `v$session.failed_over = 'YES'`, and matching other relevant columns in `v$session`.